# How to run testcases/classes as per order in testng.xml through command prompt by ant?

Tags: ant

I have 20 test cases in testng.xml file. The names are not in alphabetical order but in logical manner. When i execute from command prompt by Ant, test cases are executing by alphabetical order .

how can i execute test cases or classes in testng as in same order from command prompt by ant.

Kindly help me out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `preserve-order` attribute.  Here's an example:

```
<test name="MyTest" preserve-order="true">
  <classes>
    <class name="com.simple.test.Test1" />
    <class name="com.simple.test.Test2" />
    <class name="com.simple.test.Test3" />
  </classes>
</test>
```